# Vertical scrollbar not appearing in ssrs report in edge browser when uploaded in Dynamics CRM 365

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm, microsoft-edge

I have created a SSRS report and uploaded to Dynamics CRM 365. When I open the report and apply proper parameters and click on view report button, the report gets executed successfully in different browsers (MS Edge, IE11, Chrome). But in MS Edge browser, the report does not display vertical scroll bar. I verified the HTML rendered in Chrome as well as Edge, Chrome display the style for overflow but Edge does not.

OS: Windows 10 Pro
Browser: Microsoft Edge 40.15063.674.0
Dynamics CRM 365

Comment: We're going to need some code to understand why this is happening. If it is private information, I work on the Edge team and you can file private bugs on us (which I'd love to look at since it's an interop issue) at bugs.microsoftedge.com. If not, if you could reduce the code down and place it on jsbin.com or jsfiddle.net so we can look into where the interop issue is and hopefully provide a workaround. Thanks

Comment: This happens when you view the report from the CRM Reports section or when the reports are viewed in Dashboards?

Comment: The scenario happens when the reports are viewed from Reports section under Sales.....

Comment: It's scary that someone on the Edge team says they're curious about this error.  Edge and SSRS have never worked correctly, from Windows 8 on.  No scroll bars.  All other browsers work fine.